# Can I access a global variable in a regular expression nested within a dictionary value?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a quiz that accesses a question bank stored with a nested dictionary as follows:

```
mediumbank = {
 "q9":{"qn": "What nickname does Toph address Aang as throughout the series?", "answer": re.search(r"^twinkle-? ?toes$", userans, re.IGNORECASE)},
"q10":{"qn": "What species is Momo? ", "answer": re.search(r"^(winged)?( |-)?lemur$", userans, re.IGNORECASE)}
}
```

In the following function, I am attempting to validate the user's response using the regular expression.

```
userans = input("Answer: ")
if mediumbank["q9"]["answer"] == True:
    print("That's correct!\n")
    return True
else:
    print("That's wrong :-(")
    return False
```

However, the terminal keeps telling me that userans variable has value None. I suspect that the nested dictionary is unable to access the variable userans in the function. May I know if there's any quick fix to this?

I would like the program to return True if the user's input (stored in userans) matches the regular expression's criteria. Thanks in advance and sorry if I've missed anything obvious.

Comment: You can't evaluate the regular expression as part of the dict declaration, before `userans` exists. Either store only the regular expression string itself in the dict and call `re.search` with it later, or make `answer` a `lambda` function which you can call later.